# Why doesn't the result value appear in <input valorTotal[@item.ProductId]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Because the result value doesn't appear in input of grid column? PS: in the test input it is okay! =( (I have another input calling the function Produtos_AtualizarProdutoLista(@item.ProductId)

Thanks for the help!!!

// WEBgrid COLUM AND TESTE INPUT=========

```
grid.Column(
                format: @<input type="text" id="valorTotal[@item.ProductId]"              style="width:60%" />,
                header: "ValorTotal"
            )

                        )


<input type="text" id="teste"/>
```

//SCRIPT===============

```
function Produtos_AtualizarProdutoLista(productId) {


        var strAction = '@Url.Action("Produtos_AtualizarProdutoLista","InvoiceInput")';
        var quantity = document.getElementById('qtdCompra[' +productId+ ']').value;
        var buyPrice = document.getElementById('precoCompra[' +productId + ']').value;

$.get(strAction, { productId: productId, quantity: quantity, buyPrice: buyPrice }, function (dados) {
            $("#teste").val(dados.ValorTotal);
            $("#valorTotal["+productId+"]").val(dados.ValorTotal);
        });
```

//CONTROLLER

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Produtos_AtualizarProdutoLista(int productId, decimal quantity, decimal buyPrice)
    {

        string valorTotal = (quantity * buyPrice).ToString();

        return Json(new { ValorTotal = valorTotal }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be: 
     `id="valorTotal['@item.ProductId']"` ?